# C# - Adding data to List<Class> inside List<Class>

Tags: c#, list, listbox, touch, mouseevent

My program uses global hooks to capture and record mouse clicks. A start button is pressed which starts the recording of these clicks along with the date and time of the recording. When the stop button is pressed this records the stop time and date also.

The following shows my `List<RecordingData>` in which I capture the data I need. The problem I am having is getting `List<TouchData> touchPoints` to populate the mouse clicks and time. (Mouse clicks and touchPoints may be confusing but I am looking to get this on a touch screen eventually).

```
public class RecordingData
{
    public string _recStartDate { get; set; }
    public string _startRecTime { get; set; }
    public string _recStopDate { get; set; }
    public string _stopRecTime { get; set; }
    public List<TouchData> touchPoints { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Recording: " + 
            _recStartDate + " " 
            + _startRecTime + " - " 
            + _recStopDate + " " 
            + _stopRecTime;
    }
} 

public class TouchData
{
    public int _touchX { get; set; }
    public int _touchY { get; set; }
    public string _xyTouchTime { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "x: " +  _touchX + " y: " + 
            _touchY + " Time: " + _xyTouchTime;
    }
}
```

In my Form I have the `OnMouseDown` event to record the mouse click data and input it to my touch list. Also when `Stop_Click` is fired this stores and records all the `recordingData`.

```
List<RecordingData> recordingData = new List<RecordingData>();
List<TouchData> touchData = new List<TouchData>();

private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        xyTouchTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");

        Log(string.Format("X: {0} \t Y: {1} \t Date: {2} \t Time: {3} \n {4}", 
            e.X.ToString(), 
            e.Y.ToString(), 
            DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            xyTouchTime,
            Environment.NewLine));

        touchX = e.X;
        touchY = e.Y;

        // add these values to our touch List<>
        touchData.Add(new TouchData
            {
                _touchX = touchX,
                _touchY = touchY,
                _xyTouchTime = xyTouchTime
            });
    }

private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recStopDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
        recStopTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
        Unsubscribe();
        Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;

        //  populate List<T> with our data
        recordingData.Add(new RecordingData
        {
            _recStartDate = recStartDate, 
            _startRecTime = recStartTime,
            _recStopDate = recStopDate,
            _stopRecTime = recStopTime
        });

        //  update our listbox
        BindData();
    }

    void BindData()
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = recordingData;
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            RecordingData recData = (RecordingData)listBox1.SelectedItem;

            textBoxDebug.Text = "Start Date: " + recData._recStartDate + Environment.NewLine
            + "Stop Date: " + recData._recStopDate + Environment.NewLine
            + "Start Time " + recData._startRecTime + Environment.NewLine
            + "Stop Time " + recData._stopRecTime + Environment.NewLine
            + String.Join(Environment.NewLine, recData.touchPoints + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

In short, I have a list of recordings, each recording has its own nested list of clicks. My end goal is to show these in the `listBox`, however, I am new to this and currently having some difficulty getting this to work. Constructive criticism is appreciated.

Comment: I would say all you need is two listboxes. One with outer list, and the second with the list from the selected item of outer list.

Comment: BTW, do not use '+' with string. Use string.Format method. It is inefficient to concat your way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have any idea why recData.touchPoints in the string would be returning null? There seems to be a problem populating my nested TouchData list.

Comment: Where is it null? I cant see you assigning the property touchPoints anywhere. Why are you not using DateTime type for date data? why are you using field name "_something" with property? Property is generally names in Pascal style. That means int Property {get; set;}

Comment: Hi, touchPoints is in at the very top in the RecordingData class. DateTime has been used for the date type. the properties starting with _ are there so I do not get mixed up with the variables assigned in Form and the ones assigned in RecordingData and TouchData, thanks.